# How to duplicate rows in referenced tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables: `Contract`, `ContractElement`, `ContractElementProduct` (Contract can have multiple `ContractElement` and `ContractElement` can have multiple `ContractElementProduct`).

I want to copy one contract/ make new contract but with same Contract Elements and same `ContractElement` Products.

I can made new Contract, and new elements for that contract (equal to first contract elements), but I can't duplicate `ContractElementProduct`s?

```
insert into ContractElement
select newid(), @NewContractId, ElementId, ElementValue, Number 
from ContractElement
where ContractId = @FirstContractId
```

Comment: Where do you save the ContractElementProducts? do you have any constraints set between the tables?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "where I save  ContractElementProducts"?
There is only FK contsraint between those 3 tables...

Answer (score 0):

Given the cardinality constraints there should be three tables: Contract, ContractElement and ContractElementProducts where Contract has a foreign key to ContractElement and Contract Element has a foreign key to ContractElement.

If you are putting everything back in one table, this may not be so easy.

There is a similar question asked in https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/80943/52708 and a solution in https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/80959/52708.  That solution requires the addition of a column to the table and then a removal.  Not sure I like that so much. Look there for alternative answers to that question